# this code is showing "invalid syntax" error on the first for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

```
n=int(input())
ls=[]
ls2=[]
ls=list(map(int,input().split())
for i in range (n): # here the compiler is showing invalid syntax
    if ls[i]==0:
        ls2.append(i)
for j in range(n-2):
    if ls2[j]+2 in ls2:
        ls3.append(ls[j]+2)
print(ls3)
```

Comment: Count the parentheses in the line before!

Comment: Replace this `ls=list(map(int,input().split())` with `ls=list(map(int,input().split()))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a parentheses on the fourth line

`list( map ( int, input().split() ) )`

```
n=int(input())
ls=[]
ls2=[]
ls=list(map(int,input().split()))
#                               ^
#You were missing a paranthese
for i in range (n): # here the compiler is showing invalid syntax
    if ls[i]==0:
        ls2.append(i)
for j in range(n-2):
    if ls2[j]+2 in ls2:
        ls3.append(ls[j]+2)
print(ls3)
```